# Programmatically adding value in icheck knockout

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, icheck

I am using iCheck plugin with knockout. Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/IrfanYusanif/6tt3xywn/1/).
I want to check a option programmatically but its not working. when i check a option manually then it works. what I am doing wrong?

My HTML code is:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Condition <span data-bind="text:conditionChecked"></span> </label> //just to check the value in 'conditionChecked'.
        <div class="radio">
            <label>
                <input class="radio i-checks" type="radio" data-bind="iCheck: { checked: conditionChecked }" name="condition" value="new" required /> New
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
            <label>
                <input class="radio i-checks" type="radio" data-bind="iCheck: { checked: conditionChecked }" name="condition" value="used" required /> Used
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
            <label>
                <input class="radio i-checks" type="radio" data-bind="iCheck: { checked: conditionChecked }" name="condition" value="unboxed" readonly /> unBoxed
            </label>
        </div>
</div>
```

My js code is:

```
function ViewModel() {
            var self = this;
            self.conditionChecked = ko.observable(false);
            self.loadCondition = function () {
                  //ajax request to get condition value. Suppose ajax request returned value "used". so
                  self.conditionChecked("used");
            }
            self.loadCondition();

            ko.bindingHandlers.iCheck = { // integrating icheck plugin using bh

            init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
                //initialize icheck to the element
                $(element).iCheck({
                    radioClass: 'iradio_square-green'
                });
                $(element).on('ifChecked', function (event) {
                    var observable = valueAccessor();
                    observable.checked(event.target.defaultValue); //assigning selected value
                });
            },
            update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
                var observable = valueAccessor();
            }
        };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it this way:

1. Add a selector to the input you want to select programmatically (I added and id `unboxed` to one of radios)
2. Use `$('#unboxed').iCheck('check');` to check it

This is a side thing but better use `ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel())` instead of `ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel)`

Check fiddle: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/9etogr3b/)